# Переход на страницу и отработка скрипта на одной кнопке

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core

Есть форма на который добавляются имя фамилия и тд работника а так же хочу сделать аватарку скрипт вроде получился, но по нажатию клавиши в контроллер передаются данные но переход на другую страницу не работает

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#submit').on('click', function (evt) {
            evt.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: '',
                data: new FormData(document.forms[0]),
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                type: 'post'
            });
        });
    });
</script>`
```

View

```
div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
    <form action="~/Employee/Edit" method="post">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Surname" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Surname" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Surname" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="SecondName" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="SecondName" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="SecondName" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Position" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Position" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Position" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>

        <div>
            <input asp-for="UploadedFile">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Save" asp-route="@Model.Id" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>

    </form>
</div>
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Edit(EmployeeViewModel employee)
    {
        if (employee.Id.HasValue)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var employeeDTO = _employeeMapper.Map(employee);
                _employeeService.Edit(employeeDTO);
            }
            else
                return View(employee);
        }
        else
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var employeeDTO = _employeeMapper.Map(employee);
                _employeeService.Add(employeeDTO);
            }
            else
                return View(employee);
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перенаправление нужно делать в JS, у тебя перенаправление произойдет только на backend.
Попробуй так:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: '',
        data: new FormData(document.forms[0]),
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        type: 'post'
    }).done(function() {
        location.href = '/success.html'
    }).fail(function() {
        alert( "error" );
    })
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло)

Comment: А можно ли выбрать, папку куда сохраняться файлы будут?